# Tkinter: Frame does not expand to fill remaining space inside root widget with grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been looking into similar threads, the only ones that I could understand were suggesting to use `expand` option of `pack()` method, I was wondering if it is possible to expand a frame to fill parent widget's available space with `.grid()` method?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('MSIV Preferences')
root.geometry('850x450')

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you tried? `grid` has many documented arguments, and all of the related grid commands are documented. It's not clear why you need our help.

Comment: @BryanOakley I could pre-set width and height in my Frame widget, but I was wondering if I could set my Frame widget to expand and occupy the available space in the parent widget

Comment: Read [Grid Layout Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Comment: No, you can't do it with `grid()`.

Comment: @martineau: that is not true.

Comment: #Bryan: I've read the documentation and tried a few experiments and it sounds and appears to be the case. Prove me wrong.

Comment: @martineau: see my answer.

Comment: @Bryan: Ahhh, the `weight` option — the one thing I didn't bother trying (since there was only one row and column). Thanks! Learn something new everyday… `;¬)`

Comment: @acw1668 I read the documentation in the link, couldn't find what I am looking for.

Comment: What Bryan said in his solution can be found in the link.  So what are you looking for actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do. First, you need to tell grid to have your frame fill the space that was allocated to it, and second, you need to tell grid to allocate all extra space to the row and column that contains your frame. The second step is only necessary if you want the widget to continue to fill the space as you resize the window.

The first is done with the documented `sticky` parameter, which tells a widget to "stick" to one or more sides of the space that was allocated to it. It takes a string of compass directions. For example, "nsew" stands for "north south east west". With that, the frame will stick to all four sides of the space allocated to it.

```
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
```

The second step is to tell `grid` to allocate any extra space it has to the row and column that contains your frame. You do that by assigning a `weight` to one or more rows and columns. `grid` will allocate extra space relative to the `weight`. For example, with one column of weight 2, one of weight 1, and one of weight 0 (the default), for every three pixels of extra space, two will go one column and one will go to the other.

As a rule of thumb, when using `grid` you should always give at least one row and one column a positive weight.

In your case it would be like this:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Here is the complete program:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('MSIV Preferences')
root.geometry('850x450')

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, although I'm still hung up on why I should always give at least on row & column a positive weight?

Comment: Is it to fill the extra space in case the window has been resized?

Comment: @MehdiRezzagHebla: yes, it is to fill extra space in case the window has been resized.